Obtain average homophily coefficients from ERGM for meta-regression
I have run the following ERGM model on several classes:
mFriend<-ergm(networks$`network_id`~edges+mutual+ 
                  nodeofactor('sex') + nodeofactor('minor') +
                  nodemix ('sex', base = c(2,3))+nodemix ('minor', base = c(2,3)) + absdiff('gpa'),
                control = control.ergm(seed=1, MCMC.burnin=50000, MCMC.interval=5000), verbose=TRUE)

And have the following summary for one class:
Monte Carlo Maximum Likelihood Results:

                    Estimate Std. Error MCMC % z value Pr(>|z|)    
edges                -3.3709     0.7549      0  -4.466  < 1e-04 ***
mutual                2.7828     0.4667      0   5.963  < 1e-04 ***
nodeofactor.sex.1    -0.8513     1.0916      0  -0.780 0.435492    
nodeofactor.minor.1   0.2849     0.9734      0   0.293 0.769728    
mix.sex.0.0           2.2518     0.6215      0   3.623 0.000291 ***
mix.sex.1.1           3.2358     0.8129      0   3.980  < 1e-04 ***
mix.minor.0.0         0.1571     0.5563      0   0.282 0.777615    
mix.minor.1.1           -Inf     0.0000      0    -Inf  < 1e-04 ***
absdiff.gpa          -0.5670     0.3446      0  -1.645 0.099939 .  

The next step of my work is to do meta-regression with these classes and add covariates. To do so I need to obtain average homophily coefficients and std.errors for each class and add them to meta-regression:
rma(homophily_estimates, homophily_errors, mods = ~ minor_perc+class_size+mean_income, data=dfmeta2)

I am, however, not sure on how to proceed since this is my first time doing meta-regression. Do you have any advice?

I presume you are aiming at an analysis similar to e.g. Lubbers & Snijders in https://doi.org/10.1016/j.socnet.2007.03.002 ? I'm not sure what precisely you mean by "how to proceed?", but here's and attempt at guessing it :) I'll edit my answer if the guess is not exactly right. The steps are essentially:

Fit the model(s) to all the networks.
Create a data frame with model coefficients
Join with the class-level variables that you have (income, class size etc.)
Fit the meta-regression

For example something like that:
library(ergm)
#> Loading required package: network
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

# Let's pretend the three Sampson's networks are three classes
data(samplk)
networks <- list(samplk1, samplk2, samplk3)

# Fit the models to every network
l <- map(networks, ~ ergm(.x ~ edges + nodematch("group")))
#> Starting maximum pseudolikelihood estimation (MPLE):
# (...)
#> Evaluating log-likelihood at the estimate.

# Pretend the list of networks is named which allows
# to bind_rows() with `.id` argument
names(l) <- paste0("cl", seq(along = l))

# Data frame of coefficients
d <- map(l, broom::tidy) |> 
  bind_rows(.id = "cl")
d
#> # A tibble: 6 × 7
#>   cl    term            estimate std.error mcmc.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr> <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 cl1   edges              -2.11     0.212          0     -9.98 1.79e-23
#> 2 cl1   nodematch.group     1.73     0.318          0      5.45 5.06e- 8
#> 3 cl2   edges              -2.42     0.239          0    -10.1  5.86e-24
#> 4 cl2   nodematch.group     2.47     0.334          0      7.40 1.34e-13
#> 5 cl3   edges              -2.48     0.245          0    -10.1  6.28e-24
#> 6 cl3   nodematch.group     2.53     0.338          0      7.48 7.34e-14

# Artificial class-level data to be added
classd <- data.frame(
  cl = c("cl1", "cl2", "cl3"),
  income = rnorm(3),
  class_size = c(15, 21, 18)
)

# Join model coefs with class-level data
dd <- left_join(d, classd, by = "cl")

# Fit the meta-regression
metafit <- metafor::rma(
  estimate ~ income, 
  std.error^2, 
  data = dd,
  subset = term == "nodematch.group"
)
summary(metafit)
#> 
#> Mixed-Effects Model (k = 3; tau^2 estimator: REML)
#> 
#>   logLik  deviance       AIC       BIC      AICc   
#>  -0.5423    1.0846    7.0846    1.0846   31.0846   
#> 
#> tau^2 (estimated amount of residual heterogeneity):     0.0625 (SE = 0.2450)
#> tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):             0.2500
#> I^2 (residual heterogeneity / unaccounted variability): 36.08%
#> H^2 (unaccounted variability / sampling variability):   1.56
#> R^2 (amount of heterogeneity accounted for):            35.50%
#> 
#> Test for Residual Heterogeneity:
#> QE(df = 1) = 1.5646, p-val = 0.2110
#> 
#> Test of Moderators (coefficient 2):
#> QM(df = 1) = 1.3664, p-val = 0.2424
#> 
#> Model Results:
#> 
#>          estimate      se    zval    pval    ci.lb   ci.ub      
#> intrcpt    2.0185  0.3004  6.7190  <.0001   1.4297  2.6073  *** 
#> income     0.3102  0.2654  1.1689  0.2424  -0.2099  0.8304      
#> 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

